# How should I punctuate the first part of my list?

Tags: punctuation, lists, semicolons, periods

This is part of a resume.

> Work Experience:
>
> Freelance Translator
>
> - Translated two files of a hotel (525 words) and edited the translation of a third one (392 words) for a translation company based in Switzerland. The files consisted of food and beverage menus (May 2017);
> - Translated a reference of a marketing director (463 words) for the same company (Apr. 2017);

The list continues. I put a full stop after Switzerland. I don't know if I should use another symbol, such as a semicolon or an em-dash. I'm confused because of the lack of pronouns at the beginning of the phrases.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on a resume, it would probably be better formatted as such:

Work Experience:

Title of Position

Name of Company Worked For - Location of Company

Date1 to Date2 (timeframe you worked there)

- Translated two files of a hotel (525 words) and edited the translation of a third one (392 words). Files consisted of food and beverage menus.

After each bulletin or statement, just use a period.